# Let $p_n$ be the $n$th prime, for any integer $n$, prove that: $p_n+p_{n+1}\geq{p_{n+2}}$

Tags: inequality, summation, prime-numbers

I was just wondering about it. True or false, it seems a very interesting question to me. I'm also interested to see how this could be proven or disproven? Opinions are welcome as usual.

Regards

Comment: You cannot say that $p_n$ is **a** prime and then refer to $p_{n+1}$

Comment: I think he means n-th prime.I think this might be possible to prove similarly as Bertrands postulate.

Comment: @MooS I don't see a problem with that notation. If your sequence is $\{2,3,5,7,11\ldots \}$ and $p_n$ is an element of the sequence, then certainly $p_{n+1}$ is the next element of that sequence?

Comment: @graydad Unless it is specified, it's necessary to say that $p_n$ denotes the $n^{\text{th}}$ prime. You did exactly this in your comment. As the body of the question is, a computer wouldn't understand the question. **Edit:** Actually it would, but it would understand something different than what's intended.

Comment: @GitGud ah that makes sense, I thought this notation was more canonical.

Comment: My opinion: I think it would be true if n is sufficiently large. Counterexample exists for n small(copper.hat pointed out). As $n\rightarrow\infty$, $p_n\sim nlog(n)$. $log(n)$ would not change much when n gets large.

Comment: @DDaren `\sim` will come out as $\sim$.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen thanks

Comment: By $p_n$ I meant $n$th prime and the conjecture is simply that any prime is either equal or smaller than the sum of it's two previous prime numbers. I said equal only for the case $2+3=5$. @copper.hat

Comment: A little googling turned up the following paper http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/0909/0909.4436.pdf that credits the stated inequality to a 1934 paper of Ishikawa.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I also googled my question in various ways but didn't come up with even closer to something like that. @UmbertoP.

Comment: @user18724 some results about the existence of primes in the intervals $[x,(1+\epsilon)x]$ are due (among many others) to Nagura and later Rohrbach. I was looking for the specifics and googled "nagura rohrbach prime". Definitely not an obvious first guess for a web search!

Comment: Thanks again for explaining and the tip, but I never thought that this inequality has deeply related to the Bertrand's postulate. @UmbertoP.

Answer (score 8):

Let $p_n$ denote the $n^{th}$ prime number. Bertrand's postulate states that for any $x \ge 1$, the interval $(x,2x)$ contains at least one prime number. Thus $p_{n+1} < 2 p_n$ for all $n \ge  1$.

Suppose to the contrary that there is an index $n$ for which $p_{n+2} > p_{n+1} + p_n$. This would imply that $p_{n+2} > \dfrac 32 p_{n+1}$.

A result related to Bertrand's postulate was proved by Nagura in 1952: if $x \ge 25$ then the interval $\left[x,\dfrac 65 x \right]$ contains at least one prime number. Thus if $p_{n+1} \ge 25$ we must have $$p_{n+2} \le \dfrac 65 (p_{n+1} + 1).$$

Combining these inequalities yields $\dfrac 32 p_{n+1} < \dfrac 65 (p_{n+1} + 1)$ which forces $p_{n+1} < 1$, a contradiction. Thus $p_{n+2} \le p_{n+1} + p_n$ as long as $p_{n+1} \ge 25$.

As for the remaining cases you have $5 \le 2+3$, $7 \le 3 + 5$, $11 \le 5 + 7$, and so on all the way to $29 < 23 + 19$.

Comment: $7$ is clearly smaller than $3+5=8$ and so is $11$ $5+7=12$, then why did you use $\geq$ instead of $<$? @Umberto P.

Answer (score 1):

Using the bounds $$n\log\left(n\right)+n\log\left(\log\left(n\right)\right)-1<p_{n}<n\log\left(n\right)+n\log\left(\log\left(n\right)\right),\, n\geq6$$
 your inequality holds if$$\left(n+2\right)\log\left(n+2\right)+\left(n+2\right)\log\left(\log\left(n+2\right)\right)<n\log\left(n\right)+n\log\left(\log\left(n\right)\right)+\left(n+1\right)\log\left(n+1\right)+\left(n+1\right)\log\left(\log\left(n+1\right)\right)-2$$
 and if rewrite$$n\left(\log\left(\frac{n+2}{n+1}\right)+\log\left(\frac{\log\left(n+2\right)}{\log\left(n+1\right)}\right)\right)+2\left(\log\left(n+2\right)+\log\left(\log\left(n+2\right)\right)\right)<n\log\left(n\right)+n\log\left(\log\left(n\right)\right)+\log\left(n+1\right)+\log\left(\log\left(n+1\right)\right)-2$$
 and now note that$$n\left(\log\left(\frac{n+2}{n+1}\right)+\log\left(\frac{\log\left(n+2\right)}{\log\left(n+1\right)}\right)\right)\longrightarrow1$$
 as $n\rightarrow\infty$
 so the LHS grow up like essentialy like $\log\left(n\right)$
  and the RHS grow up essentialy like $n\log\left(n\right).$
  So if $n$
  is sufficiently large is true.